# iOS 9 web application prompting for certificates every time

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, ios9, app-transport-security

I have moved to iOS 9 beta and one of the web apps I have is prompting the users to accept the SSL Cert every day. Hence it is kind of getting cached for a day and then again prompts the user next day. This works OK with iOS 8.x.

Any idea as to why it is happening ? Anything related to ATS ?

====

Edit: ATS = App Transport Security (introduced in iOS 9)

Comment: It's a beta. Did you create this app and want to test it? Also please define ATS. Are you talking about tracking system?

To try to answer your question though, they are probably emptying the caches to get more feedback from devices. If you refresh everything, you can get crash results or whatever with less variables

Comment: App is not created by me. Found this as part of making sure the web app works OK in iOS 9. ATS is the App Transport Security feature brought in by Apple. I am not sure how would this relate to that though. The URLs that the app is  accessing was HTTPS based anyway. I specified "cache" loosely. I believe the Certs get stored in the trust store. When it is stored once, wondering how come it is getting re-set and again prompting to accept after a day.